# closely VS close

Tags: phrase-choice

> Anyway, the more I practice the play, the more closely I seem to follow her path in Venice.

In this sentence, can I use *the closer* instead of *the more closely*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a relevant usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20more%20closely%20it%20resembles%2Cthe%20closer%20it%20resembles&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

As you can see, we much prefer ***more closely*** for such relatively metaphoric contexts. Note that ***close*** literally means ***physically near***, but it's often used figuratively to mean ***similar***. When we derive *adjectives / adverbs* from that root, it's usually...

> 1: ADJ - ***closer = nearer, not so far away***
> 2: ADV - ***more closely = more like, in a more similar way***

Answer (score 1):

A strict grammarian might insist on using "more closely", but many people would use "closer" instead.